# Why is Flutter unable to read my .json asset?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, yaml

I use Flutter in Android studio to analyze and display a `json` file. The location of the file is `lib/files/results.json`. I keep on getting the following error:

```
E/flutter ( 2728): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '../files/results.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

The file is also called in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  assets:
     - lib/files/results.json
```

This is how the json file is called in the dart file:

```
var pred = await new File('../files/results.json')
```

Is there something wrong with the way I call the json file in `pubspec.yaml` or in de regular `dart` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading text asset, you can use the following method mentioned in [loading-text-assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets) document.

```
var jsonStr = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('lib/files/result.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it is *a problem with the location or path*.

The simple way is to put your json file inside the `/assets` folder (not in the lib)

Then make the reference in the `pubspec.yaml` like:

```
assets:
 - assets/results.json
```

And then try to use it like

```
var pred = await new File('assets/results.json')
```